# Trying to get Magento 1.9 orders via Rest with CFHTTP

Tags: magento, coldfusion

Im trying to get a list of orders from our Magento site using Coldfusion. CF 11.

Ive managed to authenticate and get the tokens, but each time I do a cfhttp get request to our endpoint all I get is HTML

I have variables in the session, but im just trying to dump out a list of orders

```
<cfhttp url="http://magento-test-box.local/rest/admin/V1/orders" method="post">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept" value="application/json">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="authorization : bearer" value="#variables.oauth_token#">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

is there something else i should be adding to the http request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="authorization : bearer" value="#variables.oauth_token#">
```

Try this instead:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #variables.oauth_token#">
```

*(The terms `Authorization` and `Bearer` are supposed to be case-insensitive according to the specs, but you should test both cases, in case Magento compares the case.)*